# Setting up a HIPAA secured form / file upload

Tags: uploads, security, embed

One of my clients from the Healthcare industry wants to enable customers to upload pdf in a way that would maintain HIPPA compliance. The price of third party solutions for this vary widely but my main concern is - assuming our website is protected by a EV SSL, and the form / file upload solution is HIPAA compliant. Would embedding such a solution into a WP page be secure or is it still risky?

Comment: Short answer is yes it is secure provided your storage/hosting solution is also HIPPA compliant.

Comment: in general uploading files to wordpress is not secure. You can make it if you need. Anyway no one here is likely to know what is required to be HIPPA compliant, you need to define "risky" better to make this question answerable

Comment: you also want to protect links? (i.e. not to be copiable by other people? then you have to check access for each file to each user-ID).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a developer that is/stays current on relevant security issues creates/manages the site, and a HIPAA compliant (per the regulations) hosting environment is used, forms, uploading, etc. is fine. If you proceed, note that compliance is more than technical. Policies/procedures have to be in place for using/managing the solution as well as incorporating the solution into a risk management program (required). If audited, these other items may be checked.